# Can we have Google Now type search in our app?

Tags: android, google-search, google-now

Is it possible to integrate google now features in our app? Basically I want a text or speech result for the voice search within the app.

So far the closest thing I have found is

> RecognizerIntent.ACTION_VOICE_SEARCH_HANDS_FREE

This basically launches the Google Now screen on top of the app and responds back with the voice feedback as Google Now does.

I haven't found any way yet to listen in background and get the speech result or text result which can be converted into speech by TTS engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled down with Amazon Alexa for this behavior. In case any one wants to know how to integrate Amazon Alexa with Android:

[Login with Amazon(LWA)](http://login.amazon.com/android)

[To register Android app with amazon](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/homepage.html)

[Amazon developer console(Register android app with Alexa)](https://developer.amazon.com/home.html)